# why is it necessary to write (char) while printing pattern with character in java programming language

Tags: java

```
class Pattern4 { 
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) { 
            for(int j=1;j<=5;j++) { 
                System.out.print((char)(i+64)); 
            }
            System.out.println(); 
        }
    }
}
```

In this program if I don't provide `()` to `char` keyword, I am getting a compile time error. So my question is why is it necessary to write `(char)` and then `(i+64)` and why not `char(i+64)`?

Comment: java or c++? You tagged it with both.

Comment: Because that's how cast syntax works.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: That's not what he's asking.  He is asking why `print((char)(65))` and not `print(char(65))`

Comment: @MartinBonner: I see it now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
(i+64)
```

is an `int`, because it's the sum of an `int` and an `int`.

If you want to print it as an `int`, you don't have to do anything.

```
System.out.println(i + 64);
```

If you want to print it as a `char`, you have to convert it to one:

```
System.out.println((char)(i + 64));
```

That's simply the syntax Java uses for casting.

Answer (score 0):

Because `char(65)` is method call syntax. You're not calling a method named `char` with `65` as a parameter, you're casting `65` to a `char`.

Remember that, unlike spoken languages, programming languages are carefully designed to avoid ambiguity of any kind. This is both for "user friendliness" (i.e. to make the code clearer) and from the practical necessity of writing compilers and creating correct software. Anything that would introduce ambiguity could also "break" compilers and cause subtle, difficult-to-track bugs.

Answer (score 0):

(char)int is syntax to type cast. This syntax does not take any input and its as per language design (Its not a function but language syntax). This tells compiler to accept the type as char and not as int. Java is strongly typed language and it ensures type safety. 
We need to tell compiler explicitly when we need to change type otherwise compiler will complain.

Hope this clarifies why this does not take input in parenthesis like:

```
abc(input);
```